# The tcp server socket handler don't waiting for the result of the vertical and just close the socket.How to control it?

Tags: vert.x

I'm writing a simple tcp server for short connection.

I have two vertical.

One handling the tcp request, get the eventBus and send the message to it.

Another vertical just consume and reply it.

The question is.Tcp client can't receive the result.I know the eventBus.request() is async.But don't know how to control it,just let the socket waiting for the result.

main

```java
package org.example;

import io.vertx.core.DeploymentOptions;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.VertxOptions;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions();
        options.setEventLoopPoolSize(1);
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(options);

        DeploymentOptions ruleOptions = new DeploymentOptions();
        ruleOptions.setWorker(true);
        ruleOptions.setInstances(1);

        vertx.deployVerticle("org.example.RuleVertical", ruleOptions);

        DeploymentOptions serverOptions = new DeploymentOptions();
        serverOptions.setInstances(1);
        vertx.deployVerticle("org.example.ServerVertical", serverOptions);
    }
}
```

server vertical

```java
package org.example;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.eventbus.EventBus;
import io.vertx.core.net.NetServer;

public class ServerVertical extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        EventBus eventBus = vertx.eventBus();

        NetServer netServer = vertx.createNetServer();

        netServer.connectHandler(socket -> {
            socket.handler(buffer -> {
                eventBus.request("message.id", buffer.toString(), reply -> {
                    System.out.println("Server reply: " + reply.result().body());
                    socket.write(reply.result().body().toString()).onFailure(event -> event.printStackTrace());
                });
            });
        });

        netServer.listen(1234);
    }
}
```

rule vertical

```java
package org.example;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.eventbus.EventBus;

public class RuleVertical extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        EventBus eventBus = vertx.eventBus();

        eventBus.consumer("message.id", message -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                message.reply("hello");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

client

```java
package org.example;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1234);
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
        System.out.println("Request: 1234");
        printWriter.write("1234");
        printWriter.flush();
        socket.shutdownOutput();

        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println("Response: " + sb);
        reader.close();
        printWriter.close();
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
        socket.close();

    }
}
```

Server log

```bash
Server reply: hello
io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(Object, ChannelPromise)(Unknown Source)
```

Client log

```bash
Request: 1234
Response:
```

Comment: 1. remove the socket.end call you don't need that
2. Show the code where the verticle responds to the eventbus message
3.  how are you connecting to your app? Telnet?
4. are you even receiving the messages in your else statement? i.e. can you print the buffer in your else to see if you are getting the message you expect?

Comment: I have simplify my code. All message is there. But the result is same.

Comment: First remove the thread sleep and use a set timer if you want to delay your response. Second use telnet to send your message when testing. You are closing your socket before the app can reply back hence the write on a closed socket exception

Comment: Go through my course on udemy if you are trying to learn vertx  - i have a chapter on tcp servers https://www.udemy.com/course/backend-development-with-vertx/?referralCode=063C2D57CCB957C5088C

Comment: So the server has no problem.It is the client read too fast to get the result?

Comment: the client is closing the connection before the server can respond - like i said above use telnet first

Comment: Thanks. It has confused me for a week.Saidly...